# angularjs $modal close modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

Im trying to make an angularjs Modal service.
I have an controller that opens some modal, in that modal i call original controller functions or access some variables, this part i can make it already.
I just cant close modal without clicking cancel or ok buttons, o want to make some operations in the modal, call some werbservices and the close modal manually.
Can anyone help me?

I made an working plunker here:
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bDqAll8CYwu7DGfSs7FC?p=preview)

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent2.html',
              controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
              size: size,
              scope: $scope

            });
```

Comment: You can use the modalInstance returned by modal.open to close it as well, so would need to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/SpEx6Y?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that worked. just more question, is there a way to know if some modal is open by id? without the modalInstance?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To close a $modal that you have opened you can follow these steps.

1) Inject `$modalInstance` into the controller that you specified when you created the modal. In your case you called it `ModalInstanceCtrl`.

2) Have a function in your `ModalInstanceCtrl` that calls `.close()` on `$modalInstance`.

your `ModalInstanceCtrl` should look something like this

```
angular.module('myCoolApp')
  .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.closeModal = function(){
       $modalInstance.close();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$scope.myData='all data can be';
$scope.myModalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'app/myOpen.html',
    controller: 'myOpenController',
    size: 'lg', //modal open size large
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    resolve: {
        myData: function () {
            return $scope.myData;
            }
        }
    });
$scope.modalClose = function (){
   $scope.myModalInstance.close();
}
```