# How to Close the popup box in angularjs

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Actually, i want to close the popup when i click the submit button but right now it is not closing the popup box. please check my code, and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

My code :

```
<div class="modal-footer">                      
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-r-10 waves-effect" ng-click="updateGrade()" ng-disabled="updateMenuForm.$invalid || menugradesCtrl.formData.dataLoading || menugradesCtrl.formData.processing" tabindex="14">Submit</button>

    </div>
```

Comment: you are expecting to do it with PHP ?

Comment: Aroon, No i want angular js

Comment: Remove php tag then. have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871247/angularjs-modal-close-modal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angularjs $modal close modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871247/angularjs-modal-close-modal)